# Class Library Package : sl5 target issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, portable-class-library, dnx, .net-core

I'm trying to create a shared library project containing some POCO classes used to serialize data among multiple clients (WPF / SL5 / Asp.Net).

Before Asp.Net vNext, I was using PCL without problem. Now MVC 6 is there, I tried to add Asp.Net Core 5 target to the PCL, but it seems impossible :

[image: PCL impossible]

I guess the corresponding PCL profile doesn't exists yet, so I tried to create a "Class Library Package" and [add the SL5 target](http://blog.nuget.org/20150729/Introducing-nuget-uwp.html#new-target-frameworks)

```
  "frameworks": {
      "dotnet": { },
      "dnx46": { },
      "dnxcore50": { },
      "sl5": { }
    }
```

but unfortunately, even if the target is added to the Reference tree without any error, it fails at compilation :

[image: Where is System ?]

with errors like :

```
Error CS0518 : Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported   
Error CS0246 : The type or namespace name 'String' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Like if 'Micorosft.CSharp' wasn't present for 'sl5' target... I cannot add 'mscorlib' to "sl5" dependencies, and even adding BCL doesn't helps. I'm lost.

What am I missing ?

Comment: I had similar effects when playing around with the new project system that i find somehow strange. I would not call it buggy but i dont know. My feeling is the new project system is not working easy and smooth, specially when DNX Core and DNX 4.6 and .NET platform is used all together. Also it seems there is no more a simple "nuget restore" button or something, that is not making it easier?! Try to update everything via nuget e.g. make sure there are the newest versions used everywhere. You can also play around and remove all frameworks except one from the json file and readd them one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight isn't supported by DNX projects. See the bug here https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/1837